# Remove Caption Bar - Windows 10 Dialog Window

Tags: c++, winapi, modal-dialog, windows-10

I am trying to create a small modal dialog without caption(title) bar while retaining it resizable.
But I can't remove it by any means.

https://prnt.sc/jj4hrl

Here's the dialog part of the .RC file.

```
IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 100, 100, 600,300
STYLE WS_THICKFRAME // | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX
//CAPTION "About WindowsProject2"
//FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg"
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,300,100,50,14,WS_GROUP
END
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove the caption bar from the dialog window?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change style of maximized window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855410/change-style-of-maximized-window)

Comment: If I remember correctly just using WS_POPUP should remove caption bar but that won't make your window resizable

Comment: `WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME` will make resizable popup dialog (but it's not a good idea for a modal dialog not to have caption bar)